# Кнопка "Вверх" средствами CSS

Tags: css3, html, css

Покажите пример кнопки "Вверх", которая появляется при прокрутке страницы вниз, а нажатие на неё должно возвращать пользователя наверх страницы. Желательно, средствами CSS.

Comment: Если нужно будет без использования jquery, вот здесь [**ссылка**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647871/234502) я написал код для такой кнопки на чистом javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/25yen/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#back-top").hide();

    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.class {
    min-height: 2000px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#back-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 5%;
}
#back-top a {
    width: 48px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 8px Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
#back-top a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#back-top span {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
    <div id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span></span>Вверх</a>
    </div>
</div>
```